# Bulk SMS send and receive Testing

Tags: node.js, sms

I've integrated twillio for sending and receiving sms. The system sends bulk sms to users lets say 100, and everyone replies to that message. At the moment, I've 2,3 numbers for testing, I'm looking for a tool through which I can test this in bulk for lets say 500 users. Is there any tool or library (be it paid one)?

I've check a few tools but those only support bulk sending.

Comment: Reply-All-as-a-Service, lol. What's preventing Twilio from being the solution?

Comment: Its actually reverse, reply from 100 numbers to 1.

Comment: Again, why not Twilio? It does this fine.